# Initial conditions in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-technique

My questions are about initial conditions in QM in experiment and in lab.

We consider many different initial wave functions, and we solve the problem on paper. Now, I have 2 questions about this in reality and lab:

1. ***first*** If we want to create our arbitrary initial wave function, how we do this?

   about the systems like spin that the basis of Hilbert space is finite and discrete, for example by rotating Stern–Gerlach set, we can create our initial condition but what about arbitrary wave function in arbitrary system like particle in well?
2. ***second*** question is if someone put an arbitrary system in front of us, we can't know the initial wave function unless that we measure it and then wave function collapse and after it we can put it instead of initial condition in Schrödinger equation but this is not really initial conditions we want!so is initial conditions in QM a well-defined and practical thing in lab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prepare a desired quantum state?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13329/)

Comment: thank you , it almost answer my first question.(maybe someone give better one!)but my second question being remains.

Comment: a.p., I *highly* recommend editing your post to include generous whitespace, and to correct the puntuation and other errors. As written, I (and I imagine others) will simply not make the effort to read very far into it. I've taken the liberty to do a partial edit to get you started.

Comment: it is recommended to ask a single question per thread. You will have better chances of getting an answer if you edit out the first question (which is a duplicate anyway) and focus only on the second one. Also, regarding the second question, it's not clear what you mean by "*and after it we can put it instead of initial condition in Schrodinger equation*".